# Error Code Debugging for C++ CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, scope, codeblocks

I keep getting an error message in CodeBlocks it says:

```
Error: 'Addnumbers' was not declared in this scope
```

I just started with C++ and have no idea what this means. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int fnum;
    int snum;

    cout << "Enter First number" << endl;
    cin >> fnum;
    cout << "Enter Second Number" << endl;
    cin >> snum;

    Addnumbers (fnum, snum);
    return 0;
}

int Addnumbers(int fnum, int snum){
    int ans = fnum+snum;
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the function *before* it's used:

```
int Addnumbers(int fnum, int snum);

int main()
{
}

int Addnumbers(int fnum, int snum)
{
    // ...
}
```

The first *declaration* is what is called a *prototype*, and tells the compiler that somewhere there is a function named `AddNumbers` with the specified arguments and return type. Then you can have the *definition* anywhere, even in another source file.

In C++ (as well as in C or other languages base on C) *everything* must be **declared** before it it used. That's how the compiler will know that stuff exists.

Comment: Thanks A lot! I didn't know. Is this the same for all function?  is the Main function ALWAYS last?

Comment: @Col1107 Like in my example, the declaration can be before the `main` function, they just have to be before they are used. However, placing `main` last is almost always a safe bet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either move `Addnumbers` before main, or to do a forward declaration:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Addnumbers(int fnum, int snum);

int main()
{
```